# I want to push unique elements in 3rd array by loop through two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried using techniques below but did not get the desired result, is there anyone willing to share their knowledge? It would appreciated :)

```
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < categories[i].features.length - 1; j++) {
    if (categories[i].features[j] !== categories[i].features[j+ 1]) {
      newCataegories.push(categories[i].features[j]);
      console.log(categories[i].features[j].id, j);
    }

  }
}
categories.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.features.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (newCataegories.indexOf(e) === -1) {
      newCataegories.push(e);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it

Comment: Youcometome
newfeature
DeliveryIncluded
RespondsImmediately
WorksRemotely
Wecometoyou
WorkfromHome
Youcometome
addedfeature
DeliveryIncluded
RespondsImmediately
WorksRemotely
Wecometoyou
WorkfromHome
Youcometome

Comment: as you can see the data after loop through 2d array is the above one here most of the data is repeating i just want to show the data if i didn't push the data with same id already

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` and `Array.includes` like so:

```js
const array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
const array2 = ["a", "c"]

// Filter the array by making sure the item isn't in array 2
const array3 = array1.filter((item) => !array2.includes(item))

console.log(array3) // ["b", "d"]
```

Edit: const declarations (facepalm)

Comment: There is 2d array actually, array within an array, so in that case i tried to filter through this way but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could put the values in a Set. In fact you can use the `Set` constructor callback to feed it with all the feature values, using `flatMap`. Then only remains to convert that set to an Array (if that is what you need):

```
let result = Array.from(new Set(categories.flatMap(({features}) => features)));
```